# Simple Example in using The Exception Handling Application Block in WCF Webservice

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wcf, enterprise-library

So i'm trying to use The Exception Handling Application Block from the Enterprise Library, but i just can't figure out how to do this.

This is my code from my WCF project:

```
namespace TextWebService
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface ITextWebService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        string ToLower(string inputString);

        [OperationContract]
        string ToUpper(string inputString);
    }
}
```

...

```
using Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling;

namespace TextWebService
{
    public class TextWebService : ITextWebService
    {
        public string ToLower(string inputString)
        {
            return inputString.ToLower();
        }

        public string ToUpper(string inputString)
        {
            return inputString.ToUpper();
        }
    }
}
```

#### The ASP.NEt that uses this service has a textbox and "Invoke Service Methods" button which transforms the input string like so:

[image: input string]

#### Everytime when I input large text, I get this error:

[image]

I just want a simple example how can I prevent that error from showing, or modify it **and use the exception handling application bloc**. I tried a lot of examples, but just can't seem to get it.
P.S. it must be done from WCF

Comment: Issue is not on your webservice code. Its the asp.net code behind. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81991/a-potentially-dangerous-request-form-value-was-detected-from-the-client

Comment: @loopedcode Yes I know, but this is what i get in the webservice alone :  <faultcode xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/net/2005/12/windowscommunicationfoundation/dispatcher">a:DeserializationFailed</faultcode>
         <faultstring xml:lang="en-US">The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: Error in deserializing body of request message for operation 'ToUpper'. End element 'inputString' from namespace 'http://tempuri.org/' expected. Found element 'whatever' from namespace ''. Line 6, position 38.</faultstring>

Answer (score 0):

If you are certain that the content that comes trough your project is always valid. You can try to add the following to your web.config:

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
    <pages validateRequest="false" />
</system.web>
```

---

Here's a litle bit of back info about why you are getting this error (from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81991/a-potentially-dangerous-request-form-value-was-detected-from-the-client)  post):

> ..Note that a "<" could also come from other outside sources, like a database field, a configuration, a file, a feed and so on.
>
> Furthermore, "<" is not inherently dangerous, its only dangerous in a specific context: when writing unencoded strings to HTML output (because of XSS). In other contexts different substrings are dangerous, e.g. if you write an user-provided URL into a link, the substring "javascript:" may be dangerous. The single quote character on the other hand is dangerous when interpolating strings in SQL queries, but perfectly safe if it is a part of a name submitted from a form or read from a database field...

Comment: Thanks, but this is what I get in the web service alone:  <faultcode xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/net/2005/12/windowscommunicationfoundation/dispatcher">a:DeserializationFailed</faultcode>
         <faultstring xml:lang="en-US">The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: Error in deserializing body of request message for operation 'ToUpper'. End element 'inputString' from namespace 'http://tempuri.org/' expected. Found element 'whatever' from namespace ''. Line 6, position 38.</faultstring>

Comment: @Stefan Hmm.. well WCF converts your String to XML and the '<' + '>' are giving problems. From the top of my head you will need to create a escape method where you should replace < with &lt; and > with &gt;.

Comment: Gordjin i've edited my error, the point was not to solve <> problem, but to work with the exception handling application block. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I was mis led by the image and I misinterpreted your problem